# Invalid YAML ebextensions

Tags: apache, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I'm trying to deploy an app version to elastic beanstalk but my config file formatting is incorrect.

There's a lot of escaped quotes so I don't think this is correct but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

This is the line that's causing issues;

```
    command: "sudo bash -c 'echo \"<img src=\'http://www.foo.com/img/custom_500.png\' alt=\'500\' style=\'left:50%;top:50%;position:fixed;margin-top:-235px;margin-left:-200px\'/>\"' > custom_50x.html"
```

Comment: Some more context on the error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the opening and closing Quotes, like this:

```
command: sudo bash -c 'echo \"<img src=\'http://www.foo.com/img/custom_500.png\' alt=\'500\' style=\'left:50%;top:50%;position:fixed;margin-top:-235px;margin-left:-200px\'/>\"' > custom_50x.html
```

A useful tool for determining quickly if something is wrong is to use this online [YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/).